# Closing thread is Mandatory?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using multiple threads in my python application and I am not closing any thread. If I run my code for multiple times, once in a while I am getting core dump issue. Is it necessary to close every thread I used in my code? Is it causing the core dump issue?

Comment: It's not, but it could be a culprit. How many threads are you even opening?

Comment: 10-15 threads I am using.

Comment: related: you can set `daemon=True` on your subordinate threads and then they will be killed when your main thread exits.